# iOS VoiceOver | Is there a way to modify the accessibilityLabel for a link in an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a UITextView which has NSMutableAttributedString containing 2 links (NSAttributedString) that open up in separate web pages.

UITextView -> NSMutableAttributedString -> 2 NSAttributedString

And I have set UITextView's isAccessibilityElement property to YES

Presently, the voiceover reads the contents of the NSMutableAttributedString, but when it reads the links (NSAttributedString), it says "link" as a suffix

Is there a way for me to make the voiceover speak "link that opens in a webpage" instead of it speaking just "link"?

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

NSAttributedString *link_1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:@"some_string_1"
            attributes:@{
              NSLinkAttributeName : some_url_1
            }];

NSAttributedString *link_2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
        initWithString:@"some_string_2"
            attributes:@{
              NSLinkAttributeName : some_url_2
            }];

NSMutableAttributedString *mainText = @"This is our hotel %1$@ and these are reviews %2$@";

NSRange range_1 = [[mainText string] rangeOfString:@"%1$@"];
[mainText replaceCharactersInRange:range_1 withAttributedString:link_1];

NSRange range_2 = [[mainText string] rangeOfString:@"%2$@"];
[mainText replaceCharactersInRange:range_2 withAttributedString:link_2];

textView.attributedText = mainText;
textView.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText;
textView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
```

I also tried using accessibilityAttributedHint and accessibilityAttributedLabel for this purpose, but it had no effect

Comment: Have you tried setting the [accessibilityHint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615093-accessibilityhint) or the [accessibilityLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615181-accessibilitylabel) yourself?  You may need to use [accessibilityAttributedHint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865913-accessibilityattributedhint) and [accessibilityAttributedLabel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/2865944-accessibilityattributedlabel) as you are using attributed strings.

Comment: Yes @Andrew, I tried using that, but no effect

Comment: Then it would have made sense to include that information in your question.